# com/google/common/base methods not found

Tags: java, selenium

I updates some jar files based on the dependencies list for my project.  I don't have any compilation errors; however, when I run the testNG file, I get the NoClassDefFoundError shown in the screenshot.  When I included Guava-25-0-jre.jar, I now have NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.Platform.stringIsNullOrEmpty.

Help is needed :(

[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing the jre flavor of guava with the android one? https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReleasePolicy#flavors

Comment: With guava-21.0.jar the NoClassDefFoundError was for com.google.common.base.Strings   and with guava-25.0.jar, the error was for com.google.common.base.Platform.stringIsNullOrEmpty

Comment: Well, what I mean is to replace `'com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre'` with `'com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android'` - sticking to the same major version.

Comment: @JockX - thanks for your helps.  I replaced 25.1-jre with 25.1-android - but get the same error for com.google.common.base.Platform.stringIsNullOrEmpty